# Fastest way of comparison of string elements in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for the fastest way of comparison of string element in python.

```
import os, glob, numpy as np

with open ('fname.txt','r') as fi:   ##This infile contains 9 thousands of string elements
    all_list = fi.read().splitlines()

existing_list = glob.glob('*jpg') ##This contains 5 thousands elements
existing_list = [os.path.basename(f) for f in existing_list]

remaining_list = [f for f in all_list if f not in existing_list]
for i in remaining list:
    print i
```

How to perform it in Numpy?

```
all_list = np.array(all_list)
existing_list = np.array(existing_list)
remaining_list = ???
```

Comment: just make `existing_list` a `set` and you don't need to use numpy.

Comment: The bottom half of your question doesn't match your title or the rest of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize this *without numpy* if you'd use a set:

```
existing_set = {os.path.basename(f) for f in existing_list}  # set comprehension, python2.7+
# alternatively:  set(os.path.basename(f) for f in existing_list)

remaining_list = [f for f in all_list if f not in existing_set]
```

I doubt that you'd gain a lot of performance here by using numpy even if you figured out a way to do it...

Comment: thanks, your code speed up my work. btw i could not understand what this set function did for me to accelerate the computation.

Comment: `in` for a `list` actually looks at each element in the list and compares it one by one which makes it an O(n) operation.  `in` for a `set` relys on hashing -- Essentially, you just need to hash the string and you can figure out if it is in the set in O(1) time.  Of course, this isn't free -- You loose the ability to order data in a set and the elements that you put in must be hashible.  In your case, order doesn't matter and strings are always hashible, so you're all set (pun intended).